# Transposing rows to column ORACLE SQL

Tags: sql, database, oracle, rows, transpose

I created this ORACLE SQL query that gives me all the data I need:

```
SELECT ci.record_no,
         ci.communication_no,
         ctt.description AS "TOPIC",
         ctc.description AS "CATEGORY",
         cc.sequence_no
    FROM communication_instance ci,
         communication_category cc,
         ct_category ctc,
         ct_topic ctt,
         ct_type ctp,
         department d,
         communication_record cr
   WHERE     ci.record_no = cc.record_no
         AND ci.record_no = cr.record_no
         AND cc.topic = ctc.topic
         AND cc.topic = ctt.code
         AND cc.category = ctc.category
         AND ci.communication_type = ctp.code
         AND ci.creator_department = d.code
         AND ci.record_no = '1565852'
ORDER BY 2
```

The data output looks like this:

> #### |RECORD_NO | COMMUNICATION_NO | TOPIC | CATEGORY | SEQUENCE_NO|
>
> ```
>   1565852             1           Inter     Stat          1   
>   1565852             1           Clien     Call          2   
>   1565852             2           Inter     Stat          1   
>   1565852             2           Clien     Call          2   
>   1565852             3           Inter     Stat          1   
>   1565852             3           Clien     Call          2
> ```

Please note the following relationships:

- 1 `communication_no` is 1 instance of the `record_no` (ie. there should only be 3 `communication_no` rows)
- For every unique `record_no`, there can be multiple `sequence_no`'s
- Since multiple `sequence_no`'s can exist for a single `record_no`, each `communication_no` would have 1 & 2 as their `sequence_no`'s

I am trying to get the data to display the 3 unique `communcation_no` records, and have the `topic`, `category` and `sequence_no`'s displayed in separate columns (instead of by rows). So the columns would become:

> - **RECORD_NO**
> - **COMMUNICATION_NO**
> - **TOPIC_1**
> - **CATEGORY_1**
> - **SEQUENCE_NO_1**
> - **TOPIC_2**
> - **CATEGORY_2**
> - **SEQUENCE_NO_2**

For example, `communication_no` = 1, would have 1 row and the fields would be (in order):

> - 1565852
> - 1
> - Inter
> - Stat
> - 1
> - Clien
> - Stat
> - 2

Is this possible?

Comment: What version of oracle are you using?

Comment: oracle 11g according to `select * from v$version`

Comment: do you have any insight?

Comment: The final output is not quite clear. 1) this `communication_no = 1, would have 1 row` how come it would have one row? Shouldn't it be `1 client call(instead of stat) 2` in the desired output?

Comment: if you look at the data, you'll notice that there are actually 3 `communication_no`'s for the `record_no` = '1565852'. The reason why there are duplicate lines is because of the `sequence_no`'s. There are 2 `sequence_no`'s for the `record_no` = '1565852'. So since there are 3 `communication_no`'s for the 1 `record_no`, the query is displaying 2 `sequence_no`'s for every `communication_no`'s

Comment: does that make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve the desired result, as one of the approaches, you could use `unpivot` operator. Here is an example:

```
-- sample of data from your question
with t1(record_no, comunication_no, topic, category, sequence_no) as(
  select 1565852, 1, 'Inter', 'Stat', 1 from dual union all   
  select 1565852, 1, 'Clien', 'Call', 2 from dual union all   
  select 1565852, 2, 'Inter', 'Stat', 1 from dual union all
  select 1565852, 2, 'Clien', 'Call', 2 from dual union all   
  select 1565852, 3, 'Inter', 'Stat', 1 from dual union all   
  select 1565852, 3, 'Clien', 'Call', 2 from dual
),
t2 as(
   select case 
            when record_no =
                 lag(record_no) over(order by record_no)
            then null
            else to_char(record_no)
          end                  as record_no
        , case 
            when comunication_no =
                 lag(comunication_no) over(partition by record_no
                                           order by comunication_no)
            then null
            else to_char(comunication_no)
          end                  as comunication_no
        , topic
        , category  
        , to_char(sequence_no) as sequence_no 
        , to_char(sequence_no) as sequence_no_1      
    from t1 t
   where record_no = 1565852
     and comunication_no = 1
)
select case 
         when col in ('TOPIC', 'CATEGORY', 'SEQUENCE_NO')
         then col || '_' || sequence_no_1
         else col
       end  as col
     , val
  from t2
unpivot(
   val for col in ( record_no, comunication_no
                  , topic, category, sequence_no)
)
```

Result:

```
COL                   VAL
-------------------------------
RECORD_NO             1565852
COMUNICATION_NO       1
TOPIC_1               Inter
CATEGORY_1            Stat
SEQUENCE_NO_1         1
TOPIC_2               Clien
CATEGORY_2            Call
SEQUENCE_NO_2         2

8 rows selected
```

[**SQLFiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d4716/2)

**EDIT**

```
with t1(record_no, comunication_no, topic, category, sequence_no) as(
  select 1565852, 1, 'Inter', 'Stat', 1 from dual union all   
  select 1565852, 1, 'Clien', 'Call', 2 from dual union all   
  select 1565852, 2, 'Inter', 'Stat', 1 from dual union all
  select 1565852, 2, 'Clien', 'Call', 2 from dual union all   
  select 1565852, 3, 'Inter', 'Stat', 1 from dual union all   
  select 1565852, 3, 'Clien', 'Call', 2 from dual
), 
t2 as
(
  select to_char(record_no) as record_no
       , to_char(comunication_no) as comunication_no
       , topic
       , category
      , to_char(sequence_no) as sequence_no
      , to_char(sequence_no) as sequence_no_1
  from t1
 where record_no = 1565852
   and comunication_no = 1
)
select *
  from ( select record_no
              , case 
                  when col in ('TOPIC', 'CATEGORY', 'SEQUENCE_NO')
                  then col || '_' || sequence_no_1
                  else col
               end  as col
             , val
          from t2
        unpivot(
            val for col in (comunication_no, topic, category, sequence_no)
        )
     )
  pivot(
      max(val) for col in ('COMUNICATION_NO', 'TOPIC_1', 
                           'CATEGORY_1', 'SEQUENCE_NO_1',
                            'TOPIC_2','CATEGORY_2' ,
                            'SEQUENCE_NO_2')
)
```

Result:

```
RECORD_NO  'COMUNICATION_NO'  'TOPIC_1'  'CATEGORY_1'  'SEQUENCE_NO_1'  'TOPIC_2' 'CATEGORY_2'  'SEQUENCE_NO_2' 
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------  
1565852                1      Inter        Stat              1      Client          Call               2
```

[**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d4716/5)

Comment: is it possible to have the "COL" column display as 8 columns instead of rows? Thats what im looking for

Comment: @JT2013 I'm not sure I'm following. `"COL" column display as 8 columns`!? The title of your question and desired output provided in the question, clearly state otherwise. The answer has been given to meet your desired output. So honestly, it's a bit confusing what you are really want.

Comment: I guess i wasnt clear. I will ask the question in another forum.

Comment: @JT2013 Answer has been updated. Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: thats exactly what i was looking for! Sorry for the confusion

Comment: would this SQL work if there are more than 2, topics/categories?

Comment: @JT2013 Yes, but unfortunately you will have to manually list them in the `pivot` clause - it's not dynamic. So if there is `TOPIC_3` it should be manually added in the `in` clause of the `pivot` operator along with others.